# Remove spfx webpart not in app catalog and site contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I was working on the Spfx webpart and deployed multiple of them but in Advanced Category webpart items i saw some strange webpart. How can remove it from my site collection, it is not in Site contents also App catalog.

I see an spfx webpart like %Title%

Comment: Did you check both tenant level & site collection level app catalog?

Comment: Yes checked on my tenant level it is not there, and i do not have on site collection level

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to derive the guid of the webpart:

Use [this solution](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/find-all-web-parts-in-use-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html) to get the Guid of the offending webpart on a site collection that has the webpart available.

Then run this command:

```
Set-SPOTenant -DisabledWebPartIds Guid-of-webpart-to-be-disabled
```